# Load image of size greater than 2880 in Bitmap

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am using bitmap to load the image, if the image size is more than 2880 h/w I am getting an error.

```
BitmapData src = new BitmapData(canvasToPrint.width,canvasToPrint.height)(canvasToPrint.width, canvasToPrint.height);
src.draw(_designArea);  // -- encode the jpg        
var quality:int = 115; 
var jpg:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(quality);                 
var byteArray:ByteArray = jpg.encode(src);
```

if canvasToPrint.width > 2880 or canvasToPrint.width > 2880 I will get below error at line 1
Error : invalid Bitmap

To over come the above issue I have used bitmapdataunlimited class, as mentioned in the below link.

http://blog.formatlos.de/2008/05/28/bitmapdataunlimited/comment-page-2/#comment-4870

But it only works fine for 4096 pixel of height and width, guide me if any alternative solution is there to create huge bitmap.

Answer (score 2):

If makes a difference which FlashPlayer you are targetting:

**versions VS maximum bitmapsize**

flashplayer -9 : 2880x2880 px
   flashplayer 10 : 4096x4096 px
   flashplayer 11 :   unlimited

Comment: Nice answer that's what I was gonna post. Just get the beta of flash 11 or AIR 3, Sangeeta. :)

Comment: As a side note, is there any reason for the strange value in the older flash players? I mean, 2880 - where does this number come from? I'd understand 2048 (somewhat, seems a bit low still), 2160 (double of 1080p vertical resolution) or even 2480 and 3508 (short and long side of an A4 paper sized page at 300 dpi, respectively), but 2880?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2067

Try this

Comment: thanks. i have tried this BigAssCanvas but i m not getting how to Encode using JPEGEncoder in order to convert BigAssCanvas into byte array which is used in place of BitMapdata.