# What's the reasoning behind the limit on BitmapData width/height in Flash 9 and lower being 2880?

Tags: flash

As mentioned in a comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812462/load-image-of-size-greater-than-2880-in-bitmap), the choice of exactly 2880 pixels being the maximum width and height of a [flash.display.BitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) object in Flash 9 and lower seems a bit arbitrary. I could understand, or at least guess at a reason for, quite a few choices roughly in the same ballpark, like ...

- 2048 - 2^11
- 2160 - double of 1080p vertical resolution
- 2480 or 3508 - short and long side of an A4 paper sized page at 300 dpi, respectively
- 2550 or 3300 - short and long side of a letter format sized page at 300 dpi
- 2896 - side length of a square bitmap with (almost) 2^23 pixels

... but try as I might, I can't find any reason for *exactly* 2880 pixels. So the question is, what's the reasoning behind this strange (to me) limit?

Comment: There are screen sizes of 1440 x 900 or 2560 x 1440 where 1440 is half of that size.  However, it makes little sense to me why they would choose such a size since I found no size with exactly 2880.  Graphics cards have a limit to the size of a texture they can process but it's generally a power of 2... Maybe the programmer responsible for that limit was using two screens ;)